# Converting geographic coordinates in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, coordinates, formula

I would like to convert coordinates from degrees minutes and seconds to decimal degrees in Google Sheets.

For example:
**58⁰ 09' 0.5"N** = 58 + 9/60 + 0.5/3600 = 58.1501389

In Google Spreadsheets there are functions like =left(E2,2)+(right(E2,7)/60).
But is there a way to pick numbers based on the location between sign marks (degree ⁰, minute ')  ?

For example how to find numbers between degree sign ⁰ and minute sign '
Then divide those numbers by 60?

Comment: From another topic I found some tips:
<sometext>/the text I want/<sometext>

=LEFT(MID(B1;FIND("/";B1)+1;255);FIND("/";MID(B1;FIND("/";B1)+1;255))-1)

Result: the text I want

But how to change that formula when the second sign is different from the first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given some coordinates in the exact DMS format you've stated in A1, the following formula in B1 gives the decimal form:

```
=ArrayFormula(sum(split(A1,"⁰'"")N")/{1,60,3600}))
```

N.B. when I copy a single " character into the SPLIT delimiter argument, Sheets automatically converts it to "") for some reason. It doesn't affect the split result here though.

Comment: Thank you! Very elegant solution. I managed to do the same thing with this formula =LEFT(  A1, SEARCH("⁰",   A1)-1)+(MID(  A1, SEARCH("⁰",   A1)+1, SEARCH("'",   A1) - SEARCH("⁰",   A1) -1)/60)+(MID(  A1, SEARCH("'",   A1)+1, SEARCH("''",   A1) - SEARCH("'",   A1) -1)/3600)